# "getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None " error after call this code

Tags: python, getaddrinfo

```
import imaplib, email
        with open('Accounts.txt', 'r') as f:
            data = f.readline()[1:]    
        user, password = data.split(':')
        with open(b'serverimap.txt', 'r') as good:
            serverss = good.readlines()  
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(serverss, 993)
        mail.login(user, password)
        print("logged")
        mail.select("INBOX", "Junk")
```

i get error "getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None " error after call this code my account and imap server in txt files

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` returns a list - and apparently `IMAP4_SSL()` is looking for a string.  Consider changing readlines() to just read().

```
serverss = good.read()
```

Comment: i got now  LOGIN command error: BAD [b'expected closing DQUOTE'] after call the code with good.read()

Comment: You'll need to share the `Accounts.txt` file.  It looks like you are reading the first line only, and skipping the first character.  It appears as if the mail.login() call is now failing.

Comment: when i use print the email not skipping first character so what's problem